# Regexp replace (some) numbers with letters in names

Tags: regex, perl, replace, batch-rename

I have a list of files:

```
file1_1.pdf file1_2.pdf file1_3.pdf
```

However, I want them to be renamed as

```
file1_a.pdf file1_b.pdf file1_c.pdf
```

I wonder how can I substitute letters for numbers in filenames (I use the `rename` perl script, which relies on standard regexp); unfortunately, `tr` is of no help, as it would substitute numbers where I don't want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
rename 's/_\K(\d+)(?=.pdf$)/chr ((ord "a") + $1 - 1)/e' *.pdf
```

- The `e` option to the substitution operator is used to convert the digit to a lowercase character, see [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) for more details on the `s///e` operator.
- To avoid removing the underscore in front of the digit, we use the zero-width lookbehind assertion `\K`, see [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) for more details.
- To avoid removing the `.pdf` extention following the digit, we use a `(?=pat)` zero-width positive lookahead assertion, also see [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns).